# BindingSource - can't navigate after deleting record unless I commit

Tags: vb.net, winforms, bindingsource

I am using a BindingSource to navigate through a datatable in a dataset.  I have custom Back, Forward, Delete, and New buttons.  I have all working except the Delete button.

After I delete a row, the row stays in the BindingSource (marked as "Deleted") until I commit the changes.  I understand this, but the problem is I do not want to commit the changes right after a user deletes the record.  They have the opportunity to add and delete multiple records and then click a "Save" or "Cancel" button to commit their changes all at once.

So after I delete a row using the Delete button, I can't navigate through the records anymore because the row has been marked for deletion but it still "exists", so I get an error "**Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row**" when I navigate through the records back and forward because the record is marked for deletion but you are still able to navigate through it in the BindingSource.

**It's almost like I want to have the BindingSource bound to non-deleted records only.**  That way, when a user deletes a record, it is no longer seen in the BindingSource but it gets deleted when I commit the datatable changes.

Also, is this the proper way to remove a row?:

```
    binder.RemoveAt(binder.Position)
```

Thanks very much for your help.